# Google play can not release app because of verification but there is no problem?

Tags: android, google-play-console

When I come to final step to release app google play console gave me this error

`You cannot publish applications until you complete ID verification. More details have been sent to your email.`

I did 2 -step verification and still error exist.

[image]

What can I do  ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ID verification is different from 2 factor authentication. I believe they just need to check your driver's license or government ID etc.

See this link:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9198012

Comment: Should I wait for the verification , because error still exist

Comment: I shouldn't imagine it will update instantly, perhaps give it a few hours or even check again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to this link:

https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/6829551539631522070/app-list

and click `Verify ID` to complete:

[image]